# Open a div via trigger and leave it open as long as mouse in the opened div

Tags: jquery, show-hide

A simple jQuery question
There is trigger, which opens a div, now I want the div to remain open as long as the mouse is in the div.

Eg. (trigger)->open(box)->as long as mouse in the box, leave box open.

How does one do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Gq2LX/

Comment: Oops, solved it, made a main div, and put the hover function on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the hover you have is working on your trigger div.
if you leave the trigger div your mouseOut function is called.

change your DOM a bit, and put the box INSIDE the trigger makes it work.

html:

```
<div id="trigger">
  <span>This is a trigger</span>
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

script:

```
$('#trigger').hover(function() {
    $('#box').show();
}, function() {
    $('#box').hide();
});
```

css:

```
#box {width:350px;height:400px;border:1px solid #000;display:none;}
#trigger {width:350px;}
```

i changed the width of the #trigger element (by default the div element takes 100%)
and i changed the markup (adding box inside the trigger.

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gq2LX/2/

Comment: +1 it looks like the OP is not interested on accepting this one. :) i almost feel your pain ;)

Answer (score 0):

or like that:

```
$('#trigger').mousenter(function() {
    $('#box').show();
});

$('#box').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gq2LX/6/